# MongooseJS: .populate() does not return fields from the parent model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

There are currently 2 models Product and Books; where Book inherits from Product as shown below:

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {...},
    description: {...},
    images: [{... }],
    inventory: { ... },
    department: { ... }, 
    ....
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    discriminatorKey: "kind",
  }
)
 
Model = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)  


const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    subtitle: { ...  },
    abstract: {  ... },
    publisher: {  ... },
    authors: { ...  },
    ...

},
    {
        timestamps: true, discriminatorKey: "kind",
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true }
    }
)

Book = Product.discriminator("Book", BookSchema)
```

Additionally, there is a Cart schema, which has a subdocument `products` that includes a referenced field `bookID` as shown below:

```
const cartItem = new mongoose.Schema({
    productID: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product",
        required: [true, "Please provide productID. "]
    },
    quantity: { ... },
    sessionID: { ... },
}) 

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    products: [cartItem],
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        hide: true,
    },
    sessionID: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Session"
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
})

Cart = mongoose.model("Cart", cartSchema)
```

I am using mongoosejs v-6.8.3

The issue is that .populate() on Cart instances returns only the fields from Book model (without including the fields from Product model).

```
newCart = new Cart({...}) 
newCart.save()
let populatedCart = await newCart.populate({ path: "products.productID", model: Product})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably a result of how Mongoose's discriminator feature functions. Mongoose will build a new collection for the child model and store its documents in that collection when you use the discriminator method to generate a new model that inherits from an existing model. The only collection that is queried when populate is run on the Cart instances, which only populates the fields from the Book model.
One potential fix for this problem is to explicitly include the fields from the parent model in the child model's schema. In this manner, the fields from the Product model will be included when fill is executed on the Cart instances. Another alternative is to execute the fill method with the choose option selected to include the desired fields from the parent model.
Here's an example:

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {...},
  description: {...},
  images: [{... }],
  inventory: { ... },
  department: { ... }, 
  ....
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true },
  discriminatorKey: "kind"
});

const Model = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    subtitle: { ...  },
    abstract: {  ... },
    publisher: {  ... },
    authors: { ...  },
    ...
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    discriminatorKey: "kind",
});

const Book = Model.discriminator("Book", BookSchema);
```

```
const cartItem = new mongoose.Schema({
    productID: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product",
        required: [true, "Please provide productID. "]
    },
    quantity: { ... },
    sessionID: { ... },
});

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    products: [cartItem],
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },
    sessionID: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Session"
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
});

const Cart = mongoose.model("Cart", cartSchema);

let newCart = new Cart({...});
await newCart.save();
let populatedCart = await Cart.findById(newCart._id).populate({ path: "products.productID", model: "Product", select: '-__v' });
console.log(populatedCart);
```

Comment: Thank you Anee, but this didn`t solve the problem. Also, I believe your explanation of how mongoose stores discriminator model is quite the opposite. Parent models are stored in DB, while all the fields defined in the child schemas are included based on the value of the discriminatorKey for each document .

Comment: Found the bug! For anyone interested, the issue was, I was using a plugin "mongoose-hide" wrongly. Apparently, the order of adding this plugin and compiling schema to model or extending schema matters . Always add plugins after you have compiled/extended schema.